# Recursive matrix multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

I'm working through CLRS, and I'm hoping to get some pointers (ha!) on my C++ coding style and the way I've implemented recursive matrix multiplication. The code right now seems a bit complex for something that should be rather simple, but I'm avoiding using too many built in tools so I can strengthen my baseline C++ skills. One thing that really bothers me is the need to use temporary arrays for some of the recursive calls (so that I can pass by reference and save some memory). Is there a smarter way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

void matrix_multiply_recursive(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n);
void print_matrix(double *A, int m, int n);
void merge_matrices(double *C11, double *C12, double *C21, double *C22, double *C, int n);
void zero_array(double *C, int n);
void sum_arrays(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n);

int main(){

    // why does caret not work for exponentiation?!
    int n = pow(2,4);   // only for powers of two (for now)

    double A[n];
    double B[n];
    double C[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        A[i] = i;
        B[i] = i+4;
    }

    /*
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        A[i] = (double) (rand()%100);
        B[i] = (double) (rand()%100);
    }
    */


    //print_matrix(A,sqrt(n),sqrt(n));
    //print_matrix(B,sqrt(n),sqrt(n));

    matrix_multiply_recursive(A,B,C,sqrt(n));
    print_matrix(C,sqrt(n),sqrt(n));

    return 0;

}

void matrix_multiply_recursive(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n){

    if(n==1){
        C[0] = A[0]*B[0];
    }
    else{

        int size = (int) pow(2,(n-1));

        // what a mess
        double A11[size];
        double A12[size];
        double A21[size];
        double A22[size];
        double B11[size];
        double B12[size];
        double B21[size];
        double B22[size];
        double C11[size];
        double C12[size];
        double C21[size];
        double C22[size];

        // not happy about this
        double TMP1[size]; 
        double TMP2[size];

        // zero out the C's just to be sure
        zero_array(C11, size);
        zero_array(C12, size);
        zero_array(C21, size);
        zero_array(C22, size);

        // pull out top left corners
        int k = 0;
        int l = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++){
            l=0;
            for(int j=0; j<n/2; j++){
                A11[k*(n/2)+l] = A[i*n+j];
                B11[k*(n/2)+l] = B[i*n+j];
                l++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // top right corners
        k = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++){
            l=0;
            for(int j=n/2; j<n; j++){
                A12[k*(n/2)+l] = A[i*n+j];
                B12[k*(n/2)+l] = B[i*n+j];
                l++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // bottom left corners
        k=0;
        for(int i=n/2; i<n; i++){
            l=0;
            for(int j=0; j<n/2; j++){
                A21[k*(n/2)+l] = A[i*n+j];
                B21[k*(n/2)+l] = B[i*n+j];
                l++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // bottom right corners
        k = 0;
        for(int i=n/2; i<n; i++){
            l=0;
            for(int j=n/2; j<n; j++){
                A22[k*(n/2)+l] = A[i*n+j];
                B22[k*(n/2)+l] = B[i*n+j];
                l++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // do C11
        matrix_multiply_recursive(A11,B11,TMP1,n/2);
        matrix_multiply_recursive(A12,B21,TMP2,n/2);
        sum_arrays(TMP1,TMP2,C11,n/2);
        zero_array(TMP1,n/2);
        zero_array(TMP2,n/2);


        // C12 

        matrix_multiply_recursive(A11,B12,TMP1,n/2);
        matrix_multiply_recursive(A12,B22,TMP2,n/2);
        sum_arrays(TMP1,TMP2,C12,n/2);
        zero_array(TMP1,n/2);
        zero_array(TMP2,n/2);

        // C21
        matrix_multiply_recursive(A21,B11,TMP1,n/2);
        matrix_multiply_recursive(A22,B21,TMP2,n/2);
        sum_arrays(TMP1,TMP2,C21,n/2);
        zero_array(TMP1,n/2);
        zero_array(TMP2,n/2);

        //C22
        matrix_multiply_recursive(A21,B12,TMP1,n/2);
        matrix_multiply_recursive(A22,B22,TMP2,n/2);
        sum_arrays(TMP1,TMP2,C22,n/2);


        // and now we merge
        merge_matrices(C11, C12, C21, C22, C, n/2);
        //print_matrix(C,n,n);
    }

}

void sum_arrays(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n){
    // the arrays are assumed to be n \times n
    // Add A and B and store the result in C

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            C[i*n+j] = A[i*n+j]+B[i*n+j];
        }
    }

}

// print a matrix nicely-ish
void print_matrix(double *A, int m, int n){

    std::cout << "Matrix: " << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<m; i++){
        //std::cout << "Row number " << i << std::endl;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            std::cout << A[i*n+j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n' << std::endl;
    }

}

// merge four matrices into a single larger matrix 
void merge_matrices(double *C11, double *C12, double *C21, double *C22, double *C, int n){

    //n is the size of C11 (& the other three) (i.e. if it is an 8x8 matrix, n = 8)
    //therefore, C will be 2n \times 2n

    // Pull C11 into C
    int k=0;
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        l=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            C[k*(2*n)+l] = C11[i*n+j];
            l++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    k=0;
    // Pull C12 into C
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        l=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            C[(2*k+1)*n+l] = C12[i*n+j];
            l++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    k=n;
    // Pull C21 into C
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        l=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            C[(2*k)*n+l] = C21[i*n+j];
            l++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    k=n;
    // Pull C22 into C
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        l=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            C[(2*k+1)*n+l] = C22[i*n+j];
            l++;
        }
        k++;
    }

}

void zero_array(double *C, int n){
    // zeros an n \times n array

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){

            C[i*n+j] = 0;

        }
    }

}
```